# Fallo de segmentación con nodeJS

Tags: nodejs

Instale la versión 9.0.0 de nodeJS al igual que la 8.9.0, y con ambas me ocurrió que durante el proceso de instalación se detuvo a mitad de instalación, utilizo el modulo **n** para instalar las versiones actuales, lo e utilizado muchas veces, luego cuando intente ejecutar node me lanza: **[1]    10726 segmentation fault  node**, des instale las versiones instaladas manteniendo la versión que utilizaba anteriormente, pero al ejecutar nuevamente node, me sigue sucediendo lo mismo, como podría solucionar esto, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La resolví la situación utilizando **nvm(Node Version Manager)** y reinstalando nuevamente la versión que dio error, al parecer de esta manera soluciono los errores anteriores por el modulo **n**